# Ajax button click that triggers a php file / link

Tags: ajax

I want a simple button that when I click, it shows the content from a file `file.php` ( this file when triggered it shows a random number) and if it's clicked several times refreshes the content from `file.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**PHP File:** file.php

```
<?php
    //your php code for random number...
?>
```

**HTML File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="clkMe" value="Load File" />
        <div id="response"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#clkMe").click(function(){
                    var dataString={};
                    $.ajax({                                      
                        url:"file.php",
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache:false,
                        data: dataString,
                        beforeSend: function() {},
                        timeout:10000,
                        error: function() { },     
                        success: function(response) {
                           $("#response").html(response);
                           alert(response);
                        } 
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this is what you are asking.

Happy Coding!!!